# How can I make a form selection open in a new tab?

Tags: javascript, forms

I found this script in a previous search for a way to submit a url from a radio button to the browser:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">

  function doSubmit(form) {
    var urls = form['url'];
    var i = urls && urls.length;
    while (i--) {
      if (urls[i].checked) {
        window.location = urls[i].value;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }

  </script>

  <form action="" onsubmit="return doSubmit(this)">
    <input type="radio" name="url" value="http://www.google.com"> Google
    <input type="radio" name="url" value="http://www.yahoo.com"> Yahoo
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
```

What I'm trying to do is modify the script so that it opens the url in a new tab. I've tried adding the '_blank' parameter with no luck, but I'm not even 100% sure where it would go. Has anybody got an answer for me?

Comment: Open a new tab via javascript code has to be done via `window.open`. However you can set a target to the form.

Answer (score 0):

```
  function doSubmit(form) {
    form.target = "_blank";
    var urls = form['url'];
    var i = urls && urls.length;
    while (i--) {
      if (urls[i].checked) {
        form.action = urls[i].value;

      }
    }
    return true;
  }
```

This code will do the trick. HTML5 supports the `target` attribute. The script returns `true` to allow the form action to be done. The script sets the `action` to the desired `URL`, while the form `target` is set to `_blank`, opening the url in a new window.

Comment: But it won't open the links, it will just add the links to the querystring

Comment: I'm wondering if this is a way to circumnavigate popup blockers?

Comment: @adeneo I just tested this in IE11 and it worked. The first tries indeed rendered the url as querystring, but the code above actually opened a new window.

Comment: My bad, misread that, setting the action to the url will work

Comment: Tested it and thank god browsers are smart enough to mark this method as pop up when initiated entirely from code :-)